# How do I get RxJava2 Completable andThen() working?

Tags: android, rx-java2

In my Android app I want to update parts of a database entry (using Room) and then read the entire entry from the database as soon as the update completed.

After reading the documentation of [RxJava Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) I would expect [public final  Single andThen(SingleSource next)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#andThen-io.reactivex.SingleSource-) to do the job for me. But the following code snippet logs only "Completable". "Single" and "From Single" are not logged.

```
import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.CompletableEmitter;
import io.reactivex.CompletableOnSubscribe;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;

Completable completable = Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
        Log.e(LOG, "Completable");
    }
});

Single<Long> single = Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        Log.e(LOG, "Single");
        return Long.valueOf(123);
    }
});

completable.andThen(single).subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
        Log.e(LOG, "From Single: " + aLong.toString());
    }
}, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        Log.e(LOG, "Error from Single");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Completable` never completes. You need to call `.onComplete()` on the emitter.

So your completable will look like:

```
Completable completable = Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
        Log.e(LOG, "Completable");
        e.onComplete();
    }
});
```